# PHP Propel groupBy two columns

Tags: php, propel

I have a problem with groupBy in propel:

The problem belongs to two tables.
One is called displays and the other is called customerDisplayType.
In the customerDisplayType-table there are two columns 'driver' and 'driverOptions'.
And I want to groupBy on this two columns.
So that the result could look like this:

```
Display1 -> with customerDisplayType driver "1" and driverOptions "xyz"
Display2 -> with customerDisplayType driver "1" and driverOptions "abc"
Display3 -> with customerDisplayType driver "2" and driverOptions "xyz"
```

I hope you know what I mean...

So far, I tried something like this:

```
    $displays = PiDisplayQuery::create()
    ->filterByStationId($_object->getId())    
    ->usePiCustomerDisplayTypeQuery()
        ->groupBy("CONCAT ".PiCustomerDisplayTypePeer::DRIVER.",".PiCustomerDisplayTypePeer::DRIVER_OPTIONS) // I also tried UNION instead of CONCAT
    ->endUse()
    ->find();
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the [code](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/blob/master/runtime/lib/query/ModelCriteria.php#L381), if you want to use more than one groupBy, you just have to call groupBy method several times:

```
$displays = PiDisplayQuery::create()
  ->filterByStationId($_object->getId())
  ->usePiCustomerDisplayTypeQuery()
    ->groupBy('PiCustomerDisplayType.Driver')
    ->groupBy('PiCustomerDisplayType.DriverOptions')
  ->endUse()
  ->find();
```